# New motherboard, fails to boot

Tags: cpu, motherboard, maintenance

I have an [Asrock 760GM-HDV](http://asrock.pc.cdn.bitgravity.com/Manual/760GM-HDV.pdf) motherboard with an AMD FX 8300, 2x4GB HyperX DDR3 RAM and a GTX 750ti 2GB.  I had a problem with an older motherboard that broke, so it was exchanged.

With the new motherboard installed, the monitor just won't turn on. I've tried cleaning the RAM, using just one of them, interchanged them, tried using different RAM Channels when using just one, tried using on-board GPU, cleaning GPU and etc... I don't really have another processor to test it, is there another way to be sure what is causing the problem? if this is not the right place to post this, where should I go?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! Edited.

Comment: Please unplug the power cord, open the case, and remove the coin battery (lower right corner of motherboard as shown on manual page 6 http://asrock.pc.cdn.bitgravity.com/Manual/760GM-HDV.pdf). Short the jumper pins for CLRCMOS1 (item 13, same page) and follow the instructions on page 17. Remove the short across those pins, then unplug everything except the System Header (shown pg 18 top), power cable, CPU, and one memory stick in slot A1. Instead of the GTX, use the onboard video. Will it power up? If that fails to boot, swap memory modules.

Comment: It powers up but the issue remains, the screen does not turn on. I'm really thinking it is the processor.

Comment: The jumper has been removed from CLRCMOS1? Did you switch memory modules?

Comment: Yup, it was removed and I tried switching modules and even slots.